# jQuery action whenever any select is changed (Selects inputs are added to HTML with AJAX)

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how can I make it so that a function is called whenever any select object on the page is changed?  All of my select inputs are added to the HTML by ajax functions.

Answer (score 1):

As Y. Shoham says, it's the `live` function that you are looking for. However, look closely at [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live), `change` is not supported in jQuery <= 1.3.2. Should be working as of [jQuery 1.4](http://blog.jquery.com/2009/12/04/jquery-14-alpha-1-released/).

And, yea, it should go without saying you can simply `bind` to the change event of the new elements whenever you add them. This is obviously not ideal from a code-complexity stand-point but does work ok. Just remember not to rebind the ones that already exist (unless you unbind them all first -- a waste of cycles IMO).

Comment: So you can use `bind` instead, and assign it any time you add new `select` s to the page. To avoid duplicate event calls, you can unbind+bind at each assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").live("change", function(){
    //...
});
```